# Can i ask a question about the correctness of a tab being transcribed by me

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm trying to train my ear by transcribing/tabbing parts of a song. can i ask about the correctness of the tab i wrote ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking us to review tabs you have created for correctness, that is out of scope for this site. It is effectively proof reading.

If you are having problems working out how to transcribe music into tablature, then questions on that topic can be in scope, eg 'how would I transcribe into tab a piece of music where I have a low B slide up to middle C at the same time as a pick slide from 22nd fret to the nut'

Comment: To explain further why it's out of scope: Such a question would never be useful to any other person.  Questions can be specific, but they need to be worth keeping on the site.

Comment: Programmers have a Code Review SE site. Maybe musicians could have a Score Review site someday.

Answer (score 3):

While your entire work would be out of scope, asking about specific problems in notating that you have are in scope I believe.  So for example asking how to notate a glissando, a tapped harmonic or whammy bar dive would be on topic because others may come across the same problem.